# Trigonometric Ratios/Identities Proof

Tags: trigonometry

If $\cos A=\tan B$, $\cos B=\tan A$ where $A$ and $B$ are acute angles, prove that $$\sin A=\sin B=\sqrt{\frac{3-\sqrt 5}{2}}$$

I showed that $\sin A=\sin B$ but the numerical part is out of my reach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A,B$ are acute angles, so $\sin A, \cos A, \sin B, \cos B\in(0,1)$.

$\cos A=\tan B\iff \cos A\cos B=\sin B$. $\ \ (1)$

$\cos B=\tan A\iff \cos B\cos A=\sin A$. $\ \ (2)$

$(1)(2)\implies \sin A=\sin B=:a$.

$(1)\iff \sqrt{1-a^2}\sqrt{1-a^2}=a\iff 1-a^2=a$. Solve this quadratic equation.

You'll get $a=\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$. But $\frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2}<-1$ and $\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\in(0,1)$, so $a=\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Note that $\sqrt{3-\sqrt{5}}=\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{2}}$, so $a=\sqrt{\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}}$.